# Given a longitude and latitude and a specified distance, how would I go about finding a lat,long the specified distance away from my point.

Tags: geometry

The radius of the earth is 6371km.

I have a distance n.

Given a distance k, and a latitude and Longitude , how would you find a latitude and longitude, of distance n, away from the one given?  (angle would also be a variable).

Would really appericiate any help with this. Maths isn't my strong suit but it's for a programming task.

This will eventually be used in google maps, so hopefully that gives some clarity as to my use case.

Comment: You'll need to specify more: (1) Straight-line distance, or distance along the surface? (2) Spherical earth, or ellipsoidal earth? (3) What direction are you traveling? (4) Is this a terrestrial application, or space-based application? (5) There are several measures of latitude and longitude. Which one? (One example is geodetic latitude/longitude.)

Comment: Ah ok - as I say this isn't my strength. It will be using google maps so I think spherical earth. I believe I am using geodetic lat/lang. For direction travelling - great point.  I would like it to be possible for angle to be a variable too.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between a point at latitude $90^\circ-\theta_a$ and longitude $\phi_a$ and a point at 
latitude $90^\circ-\theta_b$ and longitude $\phi_b$ on a sphere of radiaus $R$ is 
$$
D_{ab} = R \cos^{-1} ( \cos \theta_a \cos \theta_b \cos(\phi_b - \phi_a) + \sin \theta_a \sin \theta_b)
$$
using the standard convention that arc cosine is always between $0$ and $\pi$.

So the locus of all points a distance $n$ away from (latitude $90^\circ-\theta_a$,longitude $\phi_a$)
is given by the equation
$$
 \cos \theta_a \cos \theta \cos(\phi - \phi_a) + \sin \theta_a \sin \theta = \cos(n/R).
$$
You could consider this as a function giving the longitude as a function of the latitude you want being $90^\circ - \theta$:
$$
\phi = \cos^{-1} \left(  \frac{\cos(n/R)-\sin \theta_a \sin \theta }{\cos \theta_a \cos \theta} \right)
$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this out. I am currently sat with pen and paper trying to digest your notation and I'll post back with any further help I might need if that is agreeable?

Comment: OK I will check this question occasionally

Comment: Why are you talking about latitude $90^\circ − θ$? The page [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) doesn't mention anything like that.

Comment: Also, your resulting formula lacks $\phi_a$. And [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LLh42xh5/5/)'s the fiddle that makes it all work, based on formula from Movable Type.