# Filter by maximum distance from latitude and longitude

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have three variables: `latitude`, `longitude` and `distance`. I want to calculate the latitude and longitude ranges where the distance is less than the given distance.

Basing on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026466/given-a-longitude-and-latitude-and-a-specified-distance-how-would-i-go-about-fi/1026501#1026501) I'm guessing that

$$
D_{ab} > R \cos^{-1} ( \cos \theta_a \cos \theta_b \cos(\phi_b - \phi_a) + \sin \theta_a \sin \theta_b)
$$

Is it right? Could it be simplified?

Comment: Yes, that's looks right. You get it by transforming the locations to cartesion coordinates, then scalar multiply them and from that retrieve the angle between the points (seen from the center), finally you multiply the angle with the radius.

Comment: @skyking - Thanks. Should I use 90º−θ and 90º−ϕ or just the raw latitudes and longitudes?

Comment: You should note that as always you use radians to measure angles. The $\phi$ are not affected by offsetting (you can see it in the formula that you only use the difference between them anyway), the $\theta$ OTOH is 0 at the equator.

Comment: @skyking - Thanks again. Could you please check where is the error in this formula: `6371×(1÷cos(cos (40,42750×π/180) × cos(39,741285×π÷180) × cos(3,212045×π÷180 − 3,702196 × π÷180) + sin(40,42750 × π÷180) × sin(39,741285 × π÷180)))`?... because it gives me 6371

Comment: @skyking - I thing I get it. Using `acos` instead of `1/cos`.

Comment: Yes, $\cos^{-1}$ means $\arccos$